# Unable to interpret output by qiskit

Tags: qiskit, ibm-q-experience

I have built a simple 2 qubit entanglement circuit and wanted to measure using a real quantum device. I ran the below command an dthe have an output that is not what I was expecting.

qiskit.providers.ibmq.least_busy

<function qiskit.providers.ibmq.least_busy(backends: List[Union[qiskit.providers.backend.Backend, qiskit.providers.basebackend.BaseBackend]], reservation_lookahead: Optional[int] = 60) -> Union[qiskit.providers.backend.Backend, qiskit.providers.basebackend.BaseBackend]>

Could you please here.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the parenthesis `()` like that:

```
qiskit.providers.ibmq.least_busy()
```

In python, calling a function with parentheses will execute the function and return its result. On the other hand, calling it without parentheses will return a reference to the function. For more information see [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-invoking-functions-with-and-without-parentheses/).